# Php socket_close() hang my client untill the server disconect me

Tags: php, vb.net, sockets, client

This is my php client code:

```
<?php
    $service_port = 5310;
    $address = gethostbyname('192.168.40.100');

    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
    if ($socket === false)
        echo "socket_create() falló: razón: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "<br />";
    else
    {
        $result = socket_connect($socket, $address, $service_port);
        if ($result === false)
            echo "socket_connect() falló.\nRazón: ($result) " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "<br />";
        else
        {   
            $in = "Envio esto: HOLA";
            $out = 'RESPONSE: ';
            echo "ANTES: " . date("H:i:s") . "<br />"; // #1
            socket_write($socket, $in, strlen($in));
            echo "DESPUÉS: " . date("H:i:s") . "<br />"; // #2 Same time as #1
            // Leer/imprimir respuesta
            while ($out = socket_read($socket, 2048))
                echo "RESPONSE: " . date("H:i:s") . " " . $out; // #3 Same time as #2
        }
    }

    // Cerramos socket
    socket_close($socket);
    echo "BANANA: " . date("H:i:s") . "<br />"; // Always run when I got disconected from server
?>
```

I don't have access to the `server code`, but I read a little bit, it's writen in `VB.net` and it uses something like `Client.socket.send()`, I got the response and I see those echo well printed when the server disconect me, if not, my php will be hanged out in the nowhere.

**EDIT**
I added another `socket_write()` in order to tell the server that, please, disconect me, but the second one is not being sent to the server.

```
<?php
    $service_port = 5310;
    $address = gethostbyname('192.168.40.100');

    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
    if ($socket === false)
        echo "socket_create() falló: razón: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "<br />";
    else
    {
        $result = socket_connect($socket, $address, $service_port);
        if ($result === false)
            echo "socket_connect() falló.\nRazón: (" . $result . ") " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "<br />";
        else
        {   
            $in = "Envio esto: HOLA";
            $out = '';
            $response = "RESPONSE: ";
            echo "PRIMERA;";
            socket_write($socket, $in, strlen($in));
            while ($out = socket_read($socket, 2048))
                $response .= $out;
            echo $response . ";SEGUNDA;";
            $in = "close";
            $out = '';
            $response = "";
            socket_write($socket, $in, strlen($in));
            while ($out = socket_read($socket, 2048))
                $response .= $out;
            echo $response . " " . date("H:i:s");
        }
    }
    socket_close($socket);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that you are in blocking mode.

Try

```
socket_set_nonblock($socket);
```

After connecting.

This way if there is no data to read you will not hang at socket_read() and close without waiting for the server to do something.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but I need to receive a response from the server, so I think I have to use blocking mode. I will update my code.

Comment: One solution would then be to set nonblocking and then loop your read calls so if you have never received any data from the server, try the read again.  (And then set a custom timeout, or another check if you should stop trying to read).

Comment: That is a good solution, buy why it's my php hanging out without `nonblock` when reachs de `socket_close()`?

Comment: Are you sure it is hanging at socket_close?  You could try socket_shutdown($socket) before socket_close which shuts down the socket from sending and receiving.

Comment: it's ok now, thanks I was doing it in a bad way, now I have my code fixed thanks to you.